# Need to convert a Result Set to some data structure

Tags: java, sql, tree, resultset

I have a java.sql.ResultSet like this:

```
=============================
| colA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
=============================
|   1  |   1  |   1  |   1  |
|   1  |   1  |   1  |   2  |
|   1  |   1  |   2  |   3  |
|   1  |   1  |   2  |   4  |
|   1  |   2  |   3  |   5  |
|   1  |   2  |   4  |   6  |
|   1  |   2  |   4  |   7  |
|   1  |   2  |   4  |   8  |
|   1  |   3  |   5  |   9  |
|   1  |   3  |   6  |  10  |
=============================
```

The first column will always have a single value. The last column will always be unique.

I need an implementation where I want to retrieve all the items in ColD that correspond to a specific item in ColB or ColC or ColA.

for instance, if I request all items in ColD for value 2 in ColB, I should get [5,6,7,8](as a list or array).

I was wondering if a tree implementation would be a right way to go about this.

What would be the best way to accomplish is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you change your query to retrieve exactly what you need instead of doing it with code: `SELECT ColD FROM your_table WHERE ColB = 2` ?

Comment: Its not a table. Its a result of a stored proc. And I do not know beforehand what the values in ColB, ColC and ColD will be. Editing the stored proc is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select colD from tableName where colB='2';
```

Isn't the above query sufficient ?

**Update**

If you need this to be done in java then :

```
ResultSet rs=getAllDataInResultSet();//this method will return from stored procedure
List<int> resultList=new ArrayList<>();
while(rs.next()){
      int  colB=rs.getInt(2);
      if(colB==2){
       resultList.add(rs.getInt(4));
      }
}
logger.debug(resultList); //logging the final Result list
```

Output :

```
[5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: @Shailendrsingh and why it will not work , please provide me the reason so that i can improvise my answer :)

Comment: @Shailendrsingh , brother i request you to please go through this line in OP's post again 
***for instance, if I request all items in `ColD` for value `2` in `ColB`***

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I should have specified. I need it to be done in java. Its not a table. Its a result of stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a short trick, I'll have a HashMap with `keys` as the `column4` and the values as the `column1 column2 column 3` (separated by a space).

Whenever a user asks for the column values of a particular column, I'll match accordingly and give the `keys` to him.

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
String query = "select * from emp;";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

while(rs.next())
{
    hm.put(rs.getString(4), rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));
}

int fromCol = 2;
int colVal = 4;
List arr = new ArrayList();
Iterator it = hm.entrySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) 
{
      Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
      String key = pair.getKey().toString();
      String value = pair.getValue().toString();
      String []tokens = value.split(" ");

      if(tokens[fromCol - 1] .equals( colVal+""))
                arr.add(key);
}
```

Comment: Nice trick. But I had to do several other operations on the data. So I ended up building a tree.

Comment: @MuneerHudha not a problem, it made me think too. :)